# LaTeX3 - Problem with incrementing integers inside a `multicols` environment

Tags: loops, latex3

I fail in incrementing integers inside a `multicols` environment. Here is an unwanted output with two zeros instead of two 2...

[image]

Here is my M(not)WE. What kind of stupidities am I doing here?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__test_max_step_int
\int_new:N \l__test_this_step_int

\DeclareDocumentCommand\screensteps{vvv}{
    \int_set:Nn \l__test_max_step_int{#1}
    \int_set:Nn \l__test_this_step_int{0}
    
% Lets' print the material...
%   \int_do_while:nn {\l__test_this_step_int < \l__test_max_step_int} {
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \centering
            
            \int_incr:N \l__test_this_step_int
            \par\emph{Étape \ \int_use:N \l__test_this_step_int.}
        
            \columnbreak
        
            \int_incr:N \l__test_this_step_int
            \par\emph{Étape \ \int_use:N \l__test_this_step_int.}
        \end{multicols} 
    
        % JUST TO SHOW THE PROBLEM
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \centering
            
            \par\emph{Étape \ \int_use:N \l__test_this_step_int.}
        
            \columnbreak
        
            \par\emph{Étape \ \int_use:N \l__test_this_step_int.}
        \end{multicols}
%    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\screensteps{8}{numworks/?.png}{.6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, unless you really know that you want to override an existing command. Use `\NewDocumentCommand` instead.

Comment: Yes. It was just a copy-and-paste due to my laziness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using local assignments, but LaTeX environments form groups. If you want to escape them you need to use a global variable and `\int_gincr:N`.

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed it. This was real stupidity. :-( Thanks for the command.

Answer (score 1):

The integer variable has to be incremented globally. On the other hand, you can avoid global settings by using a different loop.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\screensteps{vvv}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nn { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1+1 } { 2 } }
   {
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \centering
    \projetmbc_etape:nnn { 2*##1-1 } { #2 } { #3 }
    \columnbreak
    \int_compare:nF { 2*##1 > #1  }
     {
      \projetmbc_etape:nnn { 2*##1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
    \end{multicols}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_etape:nnn
 {
  \par\emph{Étape ~ \int_to_arabic:n { #1 }.}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{Even}
\screensteps{8}{numworks/?.png}{.6}

\section{Odd}
\screensteps{7}{numworks/?.png}{.6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this proposition.